# Extjs: How to populate form with values from grid row selection

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a form and a grid. I'm trying to allow the user to select one of the rows in the grid then click a button in order to load the data from the row into the form.

Here is my view so far:

```
Ext.define('Project.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    autoScroll: true,
    height: 600,
    layout: 'border',
    bodyBorder: false,
    defaults: {
        collapsible: true,
        split: true,
        bodyPadding: 10
    },
    initComponent: function () {
        this.items = [
            {
                collapsible: false,
                region: 'center',
                margin: '5 0 0 0',
                title: 'Record Event',
                id: 'SaveEvent',
                bodyPadding: 5,
                layout: 'column',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'fieldset',
                    title: 'Event Information',
                    layout: 'anchor',
                    defaults: {
                        anchor: '100%'
                    },
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                        fieldLabel: 'Event',
                        layout: 'hbox',
                        defaults: {
                            hideLabel: 'true'
                        },
                        items: [{
                            xtype: 'combobox',
                            forceSelection: true,
                            name: 'eventTypeId',
                            width: 300,
                            store: {
                                type: 'events'
                            },
                            valueField: 'eventTypeId',
                            tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                                '<ul class="x-list-plain"><tpl for=".">',
                                '<li role="option" class="x-boundlist-item">{eventType}/{detail}</li>',
                                '</tpl></ul>'
                            ),
                            // template for the content inside text field
                            displayTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                                '<tpl for=".">',
                                '{eventType}/{detail}',
                                '</tpl>'
                            ),
                            allowBlank: false
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        layout: 'hbox',
                        margin: '0 0 5 0',
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'textfield',
                                fieldLabel: 'Event Number',
                                name: 'name',
                                allowBlank: true
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        layout: 'hbox',
                        margin: '0 0 5 0',
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'datefield',
                                fieldLabel: 'Date',
                                format: 'Y-m-d',
                                name: 'startDate',
                                invalidText: '"{0}" is not a valid date. "{1}" would be a valid date.',
                                emptyText: 'Start',
                                allowBlank: false
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'datefield',
                                format: 'Y-m-d',
                                name: 'endDate',
                                invalidText: '"{0}" is not a valid date. "{1}" would be a valid date.',
                                margin: '0 0 0 6',
                                emptyText: 'End',
                                allowBlank: false
                            },
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        layout: 'hbox',
                        margin: '0 0 5 0',
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'tagfield',
                                fieldLabel: 'Environment',
                                name: 'environmentIds',
                                width: 500,
                                store: {
                                    type: 'environments'
                                },
                                valueField: 'environmentId',
                                displayField: 'environmentName',
                                allowBlank: false
                            }]
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'container',
                            layout: 'hbox',
                            margin: '0 0 5 0',
                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'tagfield',
                                    fieldLabel: 'Geographic Location',
                                    name: 'geographicLocationIds',
                                    width: 500,
                                    store: {
                                        type: 'locations'
                                    },
                                    valueField: 'locationId',
                                    tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                                        '<ul class="x-list-plain"><tpl for=".">',
                                        '<li role="option" class="x-boundlist-item">{region}/Sub region: {subRegion}</li>',
                                        '</tpl></ul>'
                                    ),
                                    labelTpl: '{region}/Sub region: {subRegion}',
                                    allowBlank: false
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'container',
                            layout: 'hbox',
                            margin: '0 0 5 0',
                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'textfield',
                                    fieldLabel: 'Geographic Location (Out of Area)',
                                    name: 'geographicLocationNotes',
                                    width: 400,
                                    emptyText: 'e.g. 30.2500 N, 97.7500 W',
                                    allowBlank: true
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'container',
                            layout: 'hbox',
                            margin: '0 0 5 0',
                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'combobox',
                                    forceSelection: true,
                                    fieldLabel: 'Organization',
                                    name: 'organizationId',
                                    store: {
                                        type: 'organizations'
                                    },
                                    valueField: 'organizationId',
                                    displayField: 'displayName',
                                    allowBlank: false
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'container',
                            layout: 'hbox',
                            margin: '0 0 5 0',
                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'textarea',
                                    fieldLabel: 'Event Notes',
                                    name: 'eventNotes',
                                    width: 500,
                                    height: 74
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'textarea',
                            fieldLabel: 'Event ID',
                            name: 'eventId',
                            hidden: true
                        }
                    ]
                }],
                buttons: [
                    {
                        text: 'Save Event',
                        handler: function() {

                            var form = this.up('form'); // get the form panel

                            var formData = form.getValues();

                            if (form.isValid()) { // make sure the form contains valid data before submitting

                            Ext.Ajax.request({
                                    url: 'api/events/create',
                                    method:'POST',
                                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                                    params : Ext.JSON.encode(formData), 
                                    success: function(form, action) {
                                        Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result);
                                    },
                                    failure: function(form, action) {
                                        Ext.Msg.alert('Submission failed', 'There was an error.', action.result);
                                    }
                                });
                            } else { // display error alert if the data is invalid
                                Ext.Msg.alert('Submit Failed', 'Please make sure you have made selections for each required field.')
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]     
            },
            {
                title: 'Created Events',
                region: 'east',
                floatable: false,
                margin: '5 0 0 0',
                width: 500,
                minWidth: 100,
                maxWidth: 1000,
                collapsed: true,
                xtype: 'gridpanel',
                store: {
                    type: 'createdEvents'
                },
                columns: [
                {
                    header: 'Database ID',
                    dataIndex: 'eventId'
                },
                {
                    header: 'Event',
                    dataIndex: 'eventTypeId',
                    renderer: function(value, p, r) {
                        {return r.data['eventTypeName'] + '/' + r.data['eventDetail']}
                    }
                },
                {
                    header: 'Event Number',
                    dataIndex: 'name'
                },
                {
                    header: 'Start Date',
                    //this will be a problem because the form date is formatted as yyyy-mm-dd
                    dataIndex: 'startDateYear',
                    renderer: function(value, p, r) {
                        {return r.data['startDateYear'] + '-' + r.data['startDateMonth'] + '-' + r.data['startDateDay']}
                    }
                },
                {
                    header: 'End Date',
                    dataIndex: 'endDateYear',
                    renderer: function(value, p, r) {
                        {return r.data['endDateYear'] + '-' + r.data['endDateMonth'] + '-' + r.data['endDateDay']}
                    }
                },
                {
                    header: 'environments',
                    dataIndex: 'environmentIds',
                    renderer: function(value, p, r) {
                        {return r.data['environmentNames']}
                    }
                },
                {
                    header: 'Geographic Location',
                    dataIndex: 'geographicLocationIds',
                    renderer: function(value, p, r) {
                        { return r.data['geographicLocationRegion'] + '/' + r.data['geographicLocationSubregion'] }
                    }
                },
                {
                    header: 'Geographic Location Notes',
                    dataIndex: 'geographicLocationNotes'
                },
                {
                    header: 'Organization',
                    dataIndex: 'organizationID',
                    renderer: function(value, p, r) {
                        {return r.data['organizationDisplayName']}
                    }
                },
                {
                    header: 'Event Notes',
                    dataIndex: 'eventNotes'
                }
                ],
                tbar: [{
                    text: 'Add new record to event',
                    scope: this,
                    handler: this.onAddClick
                }]          
            },

        ];

        this.callParent();
    },

    onAddClick: function(sm, row, rec){

        //how to populate the form with the grid row data?

    }

});
```

I've tried this solution, but it didn't work for me:
http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/examples/kitchensink/#form-grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example does not work because there is no `form` xtype definition nor `Ext.form.Panel` presented.

Please look carefully to that [Sencha - KitchenSink](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/examples/kitchensink/#form-grid). You will see that there is definition of `Ext.form.Panel` since `KitchenSink.view.form.FormGrid` extends from that.

So your first step should be:

Change this

```
Ext.define('Project.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
```

to

```
Ext.define('Project.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
```

and this is example that could potentially works:

```
Ext.define('Project.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    autoScroll: true,
    height: 600,
    layout: 'border',
    bodyBorder: false,
    defaults: {
        collapsible: true,
        split: true,
        bodyPadding: 10
    },
    initComponent: function () {
        this.items = [
            {
                collapsible: false,
                region: 'center',
                margin: '5 0 0 0',
                title: 'Record Event',
                id: 'SaveEvent',
                bodyPadding: 5,
                layout: 'column',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'fieldset',
                    title: 'Event Information',
                    layout: 'anchor',
                    defaults: {
                        anchor: '100%'
                    },
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                        fieldLabel: 'Event',
                        layout: 'hbox',
                        defaults: {
                            hideLabel: 'true'
                        },
                        items: [{
                            xtype: 'combobox',
                            forceSelection: true,
                            name: 'eventTypeId',
                            width: 300,
                            store: {
                                type: 'events'
                            },
                            valueField: 'eventTypeId',
                            tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                                '<ul class="x-list-plain"><tpl for=".">',
                                '<li role="option" class="x-boundlist-item">{eventType}/{detail}</li>',
                                '</tpl></ul>'
                            ),
                            // template for the content inside text field
                            displayTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                                '<tpl for=".">',
                                '{eventType}/{detail}',
                                '</tpl>'
                            ),
                            allowBlank: false
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        layout: 'hbox',
                        margin: '0 0 5 0',
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'textfield',
                                fieldLabel: 'Event Number',
                                name: 'name',
                                allowBlank: true
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        layout: 'hbox',
                        margin: '0 0 5 0',
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'datefield',
                                fieldLabel: 'Date',
                                format: 'Y-m-d',
                                name: 'startDate',
                                invalidText: '"{0}" is not a valid date. "{1}" would be a valid date.',
                                emptyText: 'Start',
                                allowBlank: false
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'datefield',
                                format: 'Y-m-d',
                                name: 'endDate',
                                invalidText: '"{0}" is not a valid date. "{1}" would be a valid date.',
                                margin: '0 0 0 6',
                                emptyText: 'End',
                                allowBlank: false
                            },
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        layout: 'hbox',
                        margin: '0 0 5 0',
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'tagfield',
                                fieldLabel: 'Environment',
                                name: 'environmentIds',
                                width: 500,
                                store: {
                                    type: 'environments'
                                },
                                valueField: 'environmentId',
                                displayField: 'environmentName',
                                allowBlank: false
                            }]
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'container',
                            layout: 'hbox',
                            margin: '0 0 5 0',
                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'tagfield',
                                    fieldLabel: 'Geographic Location',
                                    name: 'geographicLocationIds',
                                    width: 500,
                                    store: {
                                        type: 'locations'
                                    },
                                    valueField: 'locationId',
                                    tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                                        '<ul class="x-list-plain"><tpl for=".">',
                                        '<li role="option" class="x-boundlist-item">{region}/Sub region: {subRegion}</li>',
                                        '</tpl></ul>'
                                    ),
                                    labelTpl: '{region}/Sub region: {subRegion}',
                                    allowBlank: false
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'container',
                            layout: 'hbox',
                            margin: '0 0 5 0',
                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'textfield',
                                    fieldLabel: 'Geographic Location (Out of Area)',
                                    name: 'geographicLocationNotes',
                                    width: 400,
                                    emptyText: 'e.g. 30.2500 N, 97.7500 W',
                                    allowBlank: true
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'container',
                            layout: 'hbox',
                            margin: '0 0 5 0',
                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'combobox',
                                    forceSelection: true,
                                    fieldLabel: 'Organization',
                                    name: 'organizationId',
                                    store: {
                                        type: 'organizations'
                                    },
                                    valueField: 'organizationId',
                                    displayField: 'displayName',
                                    allowBlank: false
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'container',
                            layout: 'hbox',
                            margin: '0 0 5 0',
                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'textarea',
                                    fieldLabel: 'Event Notes',
                                    name: 'eventNotes',
                                    width: 500,
                                    height: 74
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'textarea',
                            fieldLabel: 'Event ID',
                            name: 'eventId',
                            hidden: true
                        }
                    ]
                }],
                buttons: [
                    {
                        text: 'Save Event',
                        handler: function() {

                            var form = this.up('form'); // get the form panel

                            var formData = form.getValues();

                            if (form.isValid()) { // make sure the form contains valid data before submitting

                            Ext.Ajax.request({
                                    url: 'api/events/create',
                                    method:'POST',
                                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                                    params : Ext.JSON.encode(formData), 
                                    success: function(form, action) {
                                        Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result);
                                    },
                                    failure: function(form, action) {
                                        Ext.Msg.alert('Submission failed', 'There was an error.', action.result);
                                    }
                                });
                            } else { // display error alert if the data is invalid
                                Ext.Msg.alert('Submit Failed', 'Please make sure you have made selections for each required field.')
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]     
            },
            {
                title: 'Created Events',
                region: 'east',
                floatable: false,
                margin: '5 0 0 0',
                width: 500,
                minWidth: 100,
                maxWidth: 1000,
                collapsed: true,
                xtype: 'gridpanel',
                store: {
                    type: 'createdEvents'
                },
                columns: [
                {
                    header: 'Database ID',
                    dataIndex: 'eventId'
                },
                {
                    header: 'Event',
                    dataIndex: 'eventTypeId',
                    renderer: function(value, p, r) {
                        {return r.data['eventTypeName'] + '/' + r.data['eventDetail']}
                    }
                },
                {
                    header: 'Event Number',
                    dataIndex: 'name'
                },
                {
                    header: 'Start Date',
                    //this will be a problem because the form date is formatted as yyyy-mm-dd
                    dataIndex: 'startDateYear',
                    renderer: function(value, p, r) {
                        {return r.data['startDateYear'] + '-' + r.data['startDateMonth'] + '-' + r.data['startDateDay']}
                    }
                },
                {
                    header: 'End Date',
                    dataIndex: 'endDateYear',
                    renderer: function(value, p, r) {
                        {return r.data['endDateYear'] + '-' + r.data['endDateMonth'] + '-' + r.data['endDateDay']}
                    }
                },
                {
                    header: 'environments',
                    dataIndex: 'environmentIds',
                    renderer: function(value, p, r) {
                        {return r.data['environmentNames']}
                    }
                },
                {
                    header: 'Geographic Location',
                    dataIndex: 'geographicLocationIds',
                    renderer: function(value, p, r) {
                        { return r.data['geographicLocationRegion'] + '/' + r.data['geographicLocationSubregion'] }
                    }
                },
                {
                    header: 'Geographic Location Notes',
                    dataIndex: 'geographicLocationNotes'
                },
                {
                    header: 'Organization',
                    dataIndex: 'organizationID',
                    renderer: function(value, p, r) {
                        {return r.data['organizationDisplayName']}
                    }
                },
                {
                    header: 'Event Notes',
                    dataIndex: 'eventNotes'
                }
                ],
                listeners: {
                    scope: this,
                    selectionchange: this.onSelectionChange
                }         
            }

        ];

        this.callParent();
    },
    onSelectionChange: function(model, records) {
        var rec = records[0];
        if (rec) {
            this.getForm().loadRecord(rec);
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Imo it's better to not extend from `form` but from `Ext.container.Viewport`. From there you can put a form in the `east region` and the grid in the `center region`. You then can put a tree in the `west region` and maybe adding a `south and north region` later. There is no reason to put the grid inside the form panel..

Comment: You're right Pawel! I did not define Ext.form.Panel.